# Proper Use of Delegates and Multi-Threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates

I am writing a WCF service that has source data from multiple sources.  These are large files in various formats.

I have implemented Caching and set-up a polling interval so these files are kept up to date with fresh data.

I have constructed a manager class that basically is responsible for returning XDocument objects back to the caller.  The manager class first checks the cache for existence.  If it doesn't exist - it makes the call to retrieve fresh data.  Nothing big here.

What I would like to do to keep the response snappy is serialize the file previously downloaded and pass that back to the caller - again nothing new...however...I want to spawn a new thread as soon as the serialization is complete to retrieve the fresh data and overwrite the old file.  This is my problem...

Admittedly an intermediate programmer - I came across a few examples on multi-threading (here for that matter)...The problem is it introduced the concept of delegates and I am really struggling with this.

Here is some of my code:

```
//this method invokes another object that is responsible for making the 
    //http call, decompressing the file and persisting to the hard drive.
    private static void downloadFile(string url, string LocationToSave)
    {
        using (WeatherFactory wf = new WeatherFactory())
        {
            wf.getWeatherDataSource(url, LocationToSave);
        }
    }

    //A new thread variable
    private static Thread backgroundDownload;

    //the delegate...but I am so confused on how to use this...
    delegate void FileDownloader(string url, string LocationToSave);

    //The method that should be called in the new thread....
    //right now the compiler is complaining that I don't have the arguments from
    //the delegate (Url and LocationToSave...
    //the problem is I don't pass URL and LocationToSave here...
    static void Init(FileDownloader download)
    {
        backgroundDownload = new Thread(new ThreadStart(download));
        backgroundDownload.Start();
    }
```

I'd like to implement this the correct way...so a bit of education on how to make this work would be appreciated.

Comment: So, you have a cache, and you are updating the cache in the background? This doesn't seem like that big of a deal, I'll write you some code.

Comment: Many books have been written about threading.  You can't ask for one here, visit your local library or bookstore.

Comment: I'm not really asking about threading.  I'm more or less asking how to use delegates with threading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [Task Parallel library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) to do this:

```
//this method invokes another object that is responsible for making the 
//http call, decompressing the file and persisting to the hard drive.
private static void downloadFile(string url, string LocationToSave)
{
    using (WeatherFactory wf = new WeatherFactory())
    {
        wf.getWeatherDataSource(url, LocationToSave);
    }
    //Update cache here?
}

private void StartBackgroundDownload()
{
    //Things to consider:
    // 1. what if we are already downloading, start new anyway?
    // 2. when/how to update your cache
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(_=>downloadFile(url, LocationToSave));
}
```